# Create custom field which displays first opportunity created

Tags: opportunity, custom-field, account, date

I have a requirement where I need to capture, in a custom field on the Account Object, the date that the first opportunity was created against an Account.

Furthermore, I also would also like to do the same, but with the latest /most recent opportunity that has been created against an Account.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am currently using Professional Edition, so I cannot use workflow. Is there anyway around this using Formula /Roll-up summary fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create two rollup summaries one for the minimum date and one for the maximum date on opportunities.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup field in account to opportunity. Then using a trigger in opportunity, update related account's lookup field value.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am currently using Professional Edition so I cannot use a Trigger. Would love to solve without using code regardless!

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Professional Edition, you have two options.

1. Find a Managed Package on the AppExchange that does what you want. (unlikely)
2. Re-order the Opportunity related list in your Account Layout to sort on Created Date, displaying the oldest Opportunity first.